How to create reverse proxy using Apache that allows wan connection to the various servers hosting Apache sites on my local LAN based on DynDNS name?
I currently have a dynamic DNS account we will call mysite.dyndns.org.  Internally I have several physical machines set up to host some personal web services which I share with family and public clubs and organizations. The 1 system is Ubuntu 22.04 server which I will call machine1 or FQDN machine1.mysite.dyndns.org. The others are various VirtualBox Ubuntu servers which I will refer to as machine2 (machine2.mysite.dyndns.org) and Machine3 (machine3.mysite.dyndns.org). I am not running a local active directory domain; however, each machine is set with a hosts file which explicitly provides the IP/FQDN/hostname of each of the other machines on the local LAN. Up to now I have used port forwarding to individual machine IP on my router to provide access to these varied services; however, this is cumbersome for the general user to have to navigate to get to the services they need to access as they have to provide the port number as well as the service name. I.E. http(s)://mysite.dyndns.org:port1/site1, http(s)://mysite.dyndns.org:port1/site2, http(s)://mysite.dyndns.org:port1/site3 or items hosted on a different machine by http(s)://mysite.dyndns.org:port2/site4. I am trying to move away from port forwarding on the router to provide users an easier option to navigate to the sites, and to clean up the router. The router does not provide an option to set up a DNS host, thus the individual host files on each device.
I have set up a Virtual Box Ubuntu 22.04 server to run Apache2 proxy services through a single port forward on my router and can access the Apache2 home page externally with no issue.  This machine runs only the proxy and no other services. It should be the single point of contact to reach the other hosted services on the LAN. However, based on a great deal of suggestions from web searches around both Apache2 and Nginx, I have worked with numerous variations of defining the virtual host directives on the sites-enabled conf file for proxypass/proxypassreverse directives (by IP, by hostname, etc) have not been able to achieve a syntax or proper configuration to be able to externally connect to a service running on one of my machines that is not hosted on the proxy system itself.
I am providing a copy of the sites-enabled conf file from the proxy server, which I shall call here myproxy.conf. Note that
the machine names and site names have been edited to provide generic names and not the actual host names on my LAN.
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myproxy
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myhost1.mysite.dyndns.org
        ServerAlias myhost1.mysite.dyndns.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/HostedSite1

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass /HostedSite1 http://myhost1.mysite.dyndns.org/HostedSite1
        ProxyPassReverse /HostedSite1 http://myhost1.mysite.dyndns.org/HostedSite1

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myhost2.mysite.dyndns.org
        ServerAlias myhost2.mysite.dyndns.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/HostedSite2

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://myhost2.mysite.dyndns.org/HostedSite2
        ProxyPassReverse / http://myhost2.mysite.dyndns.org/HostedSite2

</VirtualHost>

I am also providing a copy of the hosts file which exists on each system. You will note that there are more entries there than appear in the myproxy.conf example above.
The key is to get a couple working and then
expanding the myproxy.conf to include the others when all is working.
Again, the "The examples you see are true, but the names have been changed to protect the innocent" (thank you Dragnet).
This hosts sample is taken from the myproxy system. I am providing the local lan IP addresses as 192.168.XX.Y1, Y2, Y3, etc…
in the form IP, FQDN, Hostname
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 myproxy.mysite.dyndns.org myproxy
192.168.XX.Y1 My-W10.mysite.dyndns.org My-W10
192.168.XX.Y2 myhost2.mysite.dyndns.org myhost2
192.168.XX.Y3 mynextcloud.mysite.dyndns.org mynextcloud
192.168.XX.Y4 myproject.mysite.dyndns.org myproject
192.168.XX.Y5 myhost1.mysite.dyndns.org myhost1

Providing screen shot of message (no error) or apache2 screen when going to http://mysite.dyndns.org  All of these screen shots are taken from systems outside of my lan.

Providing screen shot of messsage received when using http://machine1.mysite.dyndns.org  or http://machine1.mysite.dyndns.org/HostedSite1


Are you testing this with http: or with https:? What kind of failure are you really seeing?

I am testing with http://  (port 80) . My intent is to move to https:// (port 443) with letsencrypt certificate(s) once the general structure is working correctly.   Using just the mysite.dyndns.org url I can access the myproxy apache2 page with no issue.  When I try to access any of the other webservices hosted on devices other than the myproxy system I receive a site not found error.  No issues accessing them internally on my lan by either http://IP_address/hostedsite or http://FQDN or Hostname/hostedsite.

What actual message do you get for "site not found"? What does it look like?

added screen shots taken from systems outside of the local lan showing direct to proxy server and attempting to access one of the hostedsites running on a machine other than the proxy server.  Example Urls are provided, actual urls are redacted.

Given that error... do you actually have those subdomains defined at your DNS provider (dyndns)?

DYNDNS.COM only allows you to set to a root domain (mysite.dyndns.XXX).  This is to allow for a DNS name to map to dynamic IP address provided by your ISP.  This is a home environment, not a business, and therefore I do not have a static WAN IP address provided by my ISP.   My dyndns account allows for up to 30 root domains, but not subdomains. I did research that possibility in attempting to resolve the issue.  But I appreciate the suggestion, thank you.

You shouldn't have a DocumentRoot for a proxy. Make sure you disabled the default apache config, and enabled the proxy modules. The browser URLs should match the ServerName in your config (you currently have "machine1" in example vs "host1" in config).  You should be able to test opening the ProxyPass destination from the proxy OS, like with curl http://myhost1/somepath/. This step-by-step is wordy, but does cover most of it: https://cyberpanel.net/blog/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy#elementor-toc__heading-anchor-7


My dyndns account allows for up to 30 root domains, but not subdomains.

If your DNS provider doesn't allow creating subdomains, then you don't have subdomains – it will be impossible to access machine1.mysite.dyndns.org, through a browser or otherwise, if that entry literally does not exist in DNS.
Since the browser cannot locate your server at all, the Apache configuration is moot; it would only be consulted after a successful connection was made.

Thank you for your insight grawity.
While I can not set up subdomains through my DNS providor, it will allow me to set up webhops that point to my primary location with alternate ports.  I have tested that out and I can use my alternate naming to provide to the audience with which I wish to share my site, keep my port forwarding in place, and the persons needing to connect will not need to remember any unique port numbers or fancy naming conventions.
This acheives my ultimate goal for providing user friendly access to my site.  No proxy or reverse proxy will be required. I can delete that virtualmachine and reclaim the space.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
